# year values on the X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to make a gtraph for a dataframe:

```
   year  month    k_mean  k_min  k_max  k_count
0  1994      1  3.548387    2.0    5.0      9.0
1  1994      2  4.500000    2.0    7.0     15.0
2  1994      3  4.387097    2.0    7.0     16.0
3  1994      4  4.433333    1.0    9.0     16.0
4  1994      5  4.806452    2.0    7.0     20.0
```

The x-axis shows the index number of the record, not the value of the year column.
[image]

My code is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x0=result.year.astype(np.int32).unique()
y1=result.k_max.astype(np.int32)
x0, y1.plot(label='1')
y2=result.k_count.astype(np.int32)
x0, y2.plot(label='2')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

What's wrong ? Ideally, I would like the YEAR and the Month. Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong? You have to tell us. Not mind readers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Pandas dataframe ( with name df ), you can make your graph by using this simple command:

```
ax=plt.gca()
df.plot(kind='line',x='month',y='k_max',ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line',x='month',y='k_count',color='blue',ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

however, if you want to show both year and month one way could be to concatenate "year" and "month" before plotting them and create a new x variable as in the following:
1994-1
1994-2
...

Answer (score 0):

To plot with year and month, it would be better to adjust a bit the df in this way:

```
result['date'] = pd.to_datetime(result['year'].astype(str)+'-'+result['month'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m').dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

it creates a new column `date` that can be used as x-axis:

```
   year  month    k_mean  k_min  k_max  k_count     date
0  1994      1  3.548387    2.0    5.0      9.0  1994-01
1  1994      2  4.500000    2.0    7.0     15.0  1994-02
2  1994      3  4.387097    2.0    7.0     16.0  1994-03
3  1994      4  4.433333    1.0    9.0     16.0  1994-04
4  1994      5  4.806452    2.0    7.0     20.0  1994-05
```

After that, you can just use this to plot the 2 columns in your graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
result.plot(x='date', y=['k_max', 'k_count'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]